# xamarin UWP masterdetailpage width How to set

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I have a program with xamairn forms, One client project is UWP. The `Master` of
`MasterDetailPage` control has normal appearance  within Android and IOS platform , But it looks unfriendly within UWP platform. I know I can use Grid to replace. But, I am not sure there are some issues in the `Masterdetailpage`or I miss some key procedure to use it.

at UWP like this：

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it looks unfriendly within UWP platform. I know I can use Grid to replace. But, I am not sure there are some issues in the Masterdetailpageor I miss some key procedure to use it.

If you have not set `MasterBehavior` for `MasterDetailPage`. The `Master` will split open by default as you mentioned. Please set `MasterBehavior` according to  the following code. And you will get normal appearance.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
                  x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage" MasterBehavior="SplitOnPortrait">
</MasterDetailPage>
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, I've just added into a conditional statement MasterBehavior="Popover" for android and SplitOnPortrait for UWP